# Creating a custom event once element gets class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, dom-events

Is there a way to create custom javascript-events, that trigger once elements get a class? I want to watch all elements inside a table and process some data once one specific class gets added to them.

Is that generally possible, and if yes, how?

**edit**

I have a table with 10 rows and 10 columns. Once a player clicks one of those table cell (`<td>`-tags) there are some calculations made and the cell gets a value (a number, representing the number of mines on the surrounding fields) or pops up to be a mine. (When it has a value its class becomes `.opened` and when it has a mine its class becomes `.mine`)

Now every time the player clicks on a cell, that has no surrounding mines, its value is 0. At this time every surrounding field should be checked to see if it is also a 0. If it is, it should be unveiled (class becomes `.opened`). Now every surrounding field of this newly opened should be checked again, and again, and again - As long as none of the surrounding fields is 0 anymore.

I thought it would be the easiest way to achieve that, by simply checking for the `.opened`-class on the cell, to trigger the "chain reaction".

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML, and the code that adds the class-name?

Comment: I added some more informations. The code is quite simple (`<table> <tr> <td></td> <td></td> </tr> </table>`, just with a few more rows and cells), and the class gets added via (`e.addClass('opened')`; `e` is the element of the cell). I think the informations on my main post describe quite well what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using [Mutation Events API](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) or [DOM Mutation Observers API](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers). Read [this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function(e) {
  console.log(e.attrName, e.attrChange, e.prevValue, e.newValue, e.relatedNode)
}, false);
```

Comment: That is the right way. It works using your provided code, however my browser tells me I shouldn't be using DOMAttrModified anymore, so I tried some things with the DOM Mutation Observers API and it worked wonders. Thanks!